# Photoshop 3D export for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, photoshop

I used PS's "New 3D Extrusion from Selected Layer" to make a 3D circle. The circle came out as expected. 
I tried to export it, and then import it into Unity but Unity doesn't seem to pickup the texture.

Can any of the formats work with Unity? I tried both Collada and Wavefront and Textures is checked.

I'm using Photoshop CC 2017

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the 'Wavefront' option, but I was able to export to the Collada format properly by right-clicking in Photoshop on the Sphere in the 3D layer view and selected `Export Mesh...`

[image: Export Mesh...]

The `Original Formats` option didn't work for bringing textures across, though. When I selected `PNG`, it worked as expected.

[image: Photoshop Mesh Export Properties]

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm exporting the same. I have a 'Export 3D Layer' option under 3D. I'm not sure where you're right clicking and getting an "Export Mesh.." option. I do get the same looking dialog and tried picking PNG but I still don't seem to get the texture. When I bring it into Unity, it's just all grey

Comment: I updated the answer to include a screenshot of where I found the 'Export Mesh...' options. I also had gray textures until I fixed the texture format thing. I think I confused the export by exporting over the same name. Once I deleted all the previously exported files and re-exported, it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for that. I followed your steps and still get the same gray. Would you mind if I message you the image to see if you can get it to work?

Comment: Sure. Save the photoshop file somewhere I can download it and I'll give it a try.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to DM you, so here's the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BziOC7at5Co9TWs4Slhfc2liU0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I was able to import your mesh and I was able to get the texture to appear on the mesh, but the texture wasn't lined up correctly. Exporting as .obj didn't show the texture at all. From my experiments, it seems like the way Photoshop and Unity handle formats isn't compatible, alas.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for all your help though. I thought it was just me.